# Making LLVM fails to include $(LLVM_SRC_ROOT)/Makefile.rules

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, llvm

I'm trying to build LLVM on Windows, I've already run llvm/configure, which ran correctly. [The guide I'm following](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) says after configuring that I need to build LLVM with Make. I ran the Make command and I get the following error:

```
Makefile:151: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/Makefile.rules'. Stop
```

On line 151 of the Makefile is the following:

```
include $(LLVM_SRC_ROOT)/Makefile.rules
```

Any help would be most appreciated as I'm unfamiliar with LLVM and Make. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use cmake to compile LLVM. Just install [cmake](http://www.cmake.org), create a build directory and from within this directory invoke

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64" path\to\llvm\source\root
```

This will create a Visual Studio 2012 solution for x64. If you use a different Visual Studio version or want to use nmake then you can find a list of other generators in the [manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). Also have a look at the [LLVM docs](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) about building LLVM with cmake.

Comment: Quick question, with this method of building will I be able to link llvm-config with my C project?

Comment: @user3839220 For library linkage, you can use CMake command `execute_process` for `llvm-config` to get the flags.